# building firmware of .net micro framework for stm32f103 device

Tags: c#, c++, .net, stm32

I have configured the environment for building .net micro framework,and have installed .net mf porting kit 4.3.1 and downloaded 4.4 RTM source code.Before this,I've got a STM32F103ZET6 board.I tried to build the firmware,but there were always some errors occurred.
Here is my building log.

```
“C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\dotnetmf.proj”(build 目标) (1) ->
“C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\TinyBooter.proj”(Build 目标) (2) ->
(BuildAXF 目标) -> 



 EXEC : error : L6218E: Undefined symbol ABORTD_SubHandler (referred from FirstEntryMinimal.obj). [C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\TinyBooter.proj]
  EXEC : error : L6218E: Undefined symbol ABORTP_SubHandler (referred from FirstEntryMinimal.obj). [C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\TinyBooter.proj]
  EXEC : error : L6218E: Undefined symbol UNDEF_SubHandler (referred from FirstEntryMinimal.obj). [C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\TinyBooter.proj]
  EXEC : error : L6218E: Undefined symbol __use_no_semihosting_swi (referred from Allocator.obj). [C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\TinyBooter.proj]
  EXEC : error : L6218E: Undefined symbol CPU_GPIO_GetPinState(unsigned) (referred from TinyBooterEntry.obj). [C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\TinyBooter.proj]
  EXEC : error : L6218E: Undefined symbol HARD_Breakpoint (referred from tinyhal.obj). [C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\TinyBooter.proj]
  EXEC : error : L6218E: Undefined symbol CPU_GPIO_Initialize() (referred from tinyhal.obj). [C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\TinyBooter.proj]
  EXEC : error : L6218E: Undefined symbol CPU_GPIO_ReservePin(unsigned, unsigned) (referred from tinyhal.obj). [C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\TinyBooter.proj]
  EXEC : error : L6218E: Undefined symbol CPU_GPIO_GetPinCount() (referred from tinyhal.obj). [C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\TinyBooter.proj]
  EXEC : error : L6218E: Undefined symbol CPU_GPIO_Uninitialize() (referred from tinyhal.obj). [C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\TinyBooter.proj]
  EXEC : error : L6218E: Undefined symbol __aeabi_memclr (referred from tinyhal.obj). [C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\TinyBooter.proj]
  EXEC : error : L6218E: Undefined symbol __aeabi_memcpy (referred from tinyhal.obj). [C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\TinyBooter.proj]
  EXEC : error : L6218E: Undefined symbol __aeabi_memset (referred from tinyhal.obj). [C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\TinyBooter.proj]
  EXEC : error : L6218E: Undefined symbol _vsnprintf (referred from tinycrt.obj). [C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\TinyBooter.proj]
  EXEC : error : L6218E: Undefined symbol strcpy (referred from tinycrt.obj). [C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\TinyBooter.proj]
  EXEC : error : L6218E: Undefined symbol strncmp (referred from tinycrt.obj). [C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\TinyBooter.proj]
  EXEC : error : L6218E: Undefined symbol strncpy (referred from tinycrt.obj). [C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\TinyBooter.proj]
  EXEC : error : L6218E: Undefined symbol __aeabi_memmove (referred from WireProtocol.obj). [C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\TinyBooter.proj]
  EXEC : error : L6218E: Undefined symbol memcmp (referred from WireProtocol.obj). [C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\TinyBooter.proj]
  C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\tools\targets\Microsoft.SPOT.System.MDK.targets(298,5): error MSB3073: 命令“"C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARMCC\bin\armlink.exe"  --no_keep_init_arrays --feedback C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\FLASH\release\STM32F103\bin\Tinybooter_STM32F103_FLASH_release_MDK4.54.feedback  --debug --remove --unmangled --info sizes,totals,veneers,unused,libraries --map  --xref --symbols --callgraph --userlibpath C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\FLASH\release\STM32F103\lib --userlibpath C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\ANY_MEDIA\release\lib --libpath C:\Keil_v5\RV31\LIB  --entry EntryPoint  --symdefs C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\FLASH\release\STM32F103\bin\Tinybooter.symdefs --list C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\FLASH\release\STM32F103\bin\Tinybooter.map --output C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\FLASH\release\STM32F103\bin\Tinybooter.axf --scatter C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\FLASH\release\STM32F103\bin\Tinybooter_scatterfile.txt C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\FLASH\release\STM32F103\obj\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\FirstEntryMinimal.obj C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\FLASH\release\STM32F103\obj\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\Allocator.obj C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\FLASH\release\STM32F103\obj\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\TinyBooterEntry.obj  STM32_DA.lib cpu_analog_stubs.lib asyncproccall_pal_stubs.lib cpu_bootstrap_stubs.lib cpu_cache_stubs.lib usart_pal.lib usb_pal_stubs.lib config_pal_loader.lib Crypto_stub.lib diagnostics_pal_stubs.lib cpu_ebiu_stubs.lib events_pal_stubs.lib GlobalLock_hal_stubs.lib SH7264_Keypad.lib system_initialization_hal_loader.lib Time_pal_stubs.lib cpu_intc_stubs.lib cpu_power_stubs.lib cpu_prestackinit_stubs.lib cpu_pwm_stubs.lib SimpleHeap_config_stubs.lib SimpleHeap_stubs.lib cpu_time_stubs.lib tinycrt_pal_loader.lib TinyHal_loader.lib cpu_watchdog_stubs.lib Watchdog_pal_stubs.lib heap_pal_stubs.lib TimeService_pal_stubs.lib palevent_pal_stubs.lib Gesture_pal_stubs.lib Ink_pal_stubs.lib cpu_spi_stubs.lib piezo_pal_stubs.lib cpu_mmu_stubs.lib lcd_hal_stubs.lib cpu_LCD_stubs.lib i2c_pal_stubs.lib fs_pal_stubs.lib FS_Config_stubs.lib sockets_pal_stubs.lib COM_pal_stubs.lib Buttons_pal_stubs.lib BlockStorage_AddDevices_stubs.lib blockstorage_pal_stubs.lib batterymeasurement_hal_stubs.lib batterycharger_hal_stubs.lib backlight_hal_stubs.lib cpu_usart_stubs.lib native_double_pal.lib C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\FLASH\release\STM32F103\lib\tmp_Tinybooter.lib”已退出，代码为 1。 [C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyBooter\TinyBooter.proj]


“C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\dotnetmf.proj”(build 目标) (1) ->
“C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyCLR\TinyCLR.proj”(Build 目标) (62) ->
  EXEC : Fatal error : L6002U: Could not open file PreStackInit_HAL_STM32F103.lib: No such file or directory [C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyCLR\TinyCLR.proj]
  C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\tools\targets\Microsoft.SPOT.System.MDK.targets(298,5): error MSB3073: 命令“"C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARMCC\bin\armlink.exe"  --keep *(.init_array) --no_keep_init_arrays --feedback C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\FLASH\release\STM32F103\bin\tinyclr_STM32F103_FLASH_release_MDK4.54.feedback  --debug --remove --unmangled --info sizes,totals,veneers,unused,libraries --map  --xref --symbols --callgraph --userlibpath C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\FLASH\release\STM32F103\lib --userlibpath C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\ANY_MEDIA\release\lib --libpath C:\Keil_v5\RV31\LIB  --entry EntryPoint  --symdefs C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\FLASH\release\STM32F103\bin\tinyclr.symdefs --list C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\FLASH\release\STM32F103\bin\tinyclr.map --output C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\FLASH\release\STM32F103\bin\tinyclr.axf --scatter C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\FLASH\release\STM32F103\bin\tinyclr_scatterfile.txt C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\FLASH\release\STM32F103\obj\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyCLR\tinyclr_dat.obj C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\FLASH\release\STM32F103\obj\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyCLR\allocator.obj C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\FLASH\release\STM32F103\obj\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyCLR\tinyclr.obj C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\FLASH\release\STM32F103\lib\InteropAssembliesTable.lib openssl_pal_stubs.lib batterycharger_hal_stubs.lib batterymeasurement_hal_stubs.lib fs_pal.lib i2c_pal.lib usart_pal.lib STM32_DA.lib STM32_Analog.lib STM32_bootstrap.lib usb_pal_stubs.lib diagnostics_pal_stubs.lib STM32_GPIO.lib cpu_pwm_stubs.lib STM32_time.lib TinyHal.lib FS_FAT.lib cpu_spi_stubs.lib STM32_I2C.lib graphics_pal.lib COM_pal.lib cpu_usb_stubs.lib sockets_pal_stubs.lib AsyncProc_PAL_STM32F103.lib Cache_HAL_STM32F103.lib Config_PAL_STM32F103.lib EBIU_HAL_STM32F103.lib Events_PAL_STM32F103.lib FileSystem_Config_PAL_STM32F103.lib GlobalLock_HAL_STM32F103.lib InterruptController_HAL_STM32F103.lib LargeBuffer_HAL_STM32F103.lib LCD_HAL_STM32F103.lib LCDController_HAL_STM32F103.lib MFUpdate_PAL_STM32F103.lib Power_HAL_STM32F103.lib PreStackInit_HAL_STM32F103.lib SimpleHeap_Config_PAL_STM32F103.lib SimpleHeap_PAL_STM32F103.lib Time_PAL_STM32F103.lib TinyCRT_PAL_STM32F103.lib USART_HAL_STM32F103.lib VirtualKey_HAL_STM32F103.lib Watchdog_HAL_STM32F103.lib Watchdog_PAL_STM32F103.lib Crypto_stub.lib system_initialization_hal.lib Buttons_pal.lib heap_pal.lib cpu_mmu_stubs.lib palevent_pal.lib piezo_pal.lib piezo_config_pal_stubs.lib BlockStorage_AddDevices_stubs.lib blockstorage_pal_stubs.lib backlight_hal_stubs.lib TimeService_pal_stubs.lib Gesture_pal_stubs.lib Ink_pal_stubs.lib native_double_pal.lib C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB2\MDK4.54\le\FLASH\release\STM32F103\lib\tmp_tinyclr.lib”已退出，代码为 1。 [C:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\STM32F103\TinyCLR\TinyCLR.proj]

313 个警告
22 个错误

已用时间 00:24:49.76
```

What can I do with these errors?